# RxSwift Observeable doesn't update tableview on data change

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift

I setup the tableview and want to update the UI as soon as the data changes. I simulate a data change with the dispatcher. But the problem is, that the table won't update. Can someone explain how to setup a tableview with RxSwift to update it's cell on data change?

```
  @IBOutlet private var tableView: UITableView!
  let europeanChocolates: Variable<[Chocolate]> = Variable([])
  let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

  //MARK: View Lifecycle

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = "Chocolate!!!"
    setupCellConfiguration()
    europeanChocolates.value = Chocolate.ofEurope
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
      var choclate = self.europeanChocolates.value[0]
      choclate.countryName = "Denmark"
    }

  }

  //MARK: Rx Setup

  private func setupCellConfiguration() {
    europeanChocolates.asObservable().bindTo(tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: ChocolateCell.Identifier, cellType: ChocolateCell.self)) {
      row, chocolate, cell in
      cell.configureWithChocolate(chocolate: chocolate)
    }
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didnt provide implementation of your Chocolate, but I assume it's structure, in that case you are not changing anything, because in

```
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
  var choclate = self.europeanChocolates.value[0]
  choclate.countryName = "Denmark"
}
```

your chocolate from europeanChocolates is copied to new var choclate, but you never save it. You can easily check it, if you try this

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = "Chocolate!!!"
    setupCellConfiguration()
    europeanChocolates.value = Chocolate.ofEurope
    europeanChocolates.asObservable().subscribe(onNext: { choco in
        print("choco changed \(choco)")
    })
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
      var choclate = self.europeanChocolates.value[0]
      choclate.countryName = "Denmark"
    }

  }
```

I think it won't print "choco changed". If Im right this should help you:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = "Chocolate!!!"
    setupCellConfiguration()
    europeanChocolates.value = Chocolate.ofEurope
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
      var choclate = self.europeanChocolates.value[0]
      choclate.countryName = "Denmark"
      self.europeanChocolates.value[0] = choclate
    }

  }
```

If it doesn't help, please provide implementation of Chocolate and ChocolateCell

Answer (score 0):

In swift5 the Variable has been deprecated. So preferably you should use the behaviour subjects. To pass value in it use OnNext function. If it bind with the table view then it will automatically refresh the new data.

Answer (score -7):

You have to reload the tableView just after the data change. To reload tableView call this:

```
this.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: This is little bit off-topic, because question was about RxCocoa and observables, not how to reload data.